# Handle correlations in Load runner and use them in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load, correlation

I am trying to record SAP scripts in Load Runner and correlate the business flows. I want to convert the script to JMX to be used in JMeter.

My query is will this be a good option to go forward with running SAP business flow testing using JMeter? As the company won't spend money on Load runner enterprise version.

Secondly, if I convert the already correlated script in Load runner to JMeter will the script be auto correlated ? Or do I have to do the correlation back again?

Note: For the above point I have gone through one of the posts in Stack Overflow where they have mentioned how to convert the script from Load runner to JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [SAP](https://www.sap.com/index.html) is a company which produces a lot of applications and these applications rely on different [network protocols](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/communication_technologies/communication_technologies_network_protocols.htm) so you need to ensure that the protocol(s) in scope is (are) supported by JMeter which might not be the case especially when it comes to [SAP GUI](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/communication_technologies/communication_technologies_network_protocols.htm)

For "normal" [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) it's not a problem to convert LoadRunner scripts into JMeter using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder but you will have to perform correlation yourself. Alternative options are:

- Use [JMeter Correlation Recorder Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-jmeter-correlation-recorder-plugin) where you can define correlation rules and they will be applied to downstream HTTP Request samplers
- Use external recording solution like [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder) which is capable of exporting recorded scripts in "SmartJMX" mode with automated detection and correlation of the dynamic parameters